# Controller structure for a browser game module with filters and pagination

Tags: javascript, angular.js

To get an idea of what the controller code reflects, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Basically, the idea is that you print out a list of football players which you can then filter by their name, price, field position, and team. I'm not sure whether it's better to handle all the scope logic within a single controller, or break it down into separate controllers, isolating the filters from the player list, pagination, and so on. I'm currently going with the single controller approach, and here's what I have:

```
app.controller('playersController', function($scope, $filter, minMax, buildOptions, PlayersModel, TeamsModel, CommonValues){
    $scope.basehref         = CommonValues.getBaseHref();
    $scope.imgbase          = CommonValues.getImgBase();
    $scope.players          = PlayersModel;
    $scope.teams            = TeamsModel;
    $scope.predicate        = 'team.name';
    $scope.minMax           = minMax($scope.players);

    $scope.filters          = { // filter model 
        searchString: '',       // string input from user
        selectedTeam: {},       // selected team
        selectedTeamMs: [],     // selected teams from multiselect
        roles: {
            1: true,            // forward
            2: true,            // defense
            3: true,            // midfield
            4: true             // goalie 
        },
        slider: {               // set up boundaries for slider filter
            min: $scope.minMax[0],
            max: $scope.minMax[1],
            step: 10000
        },
        pagination: {           // set up pagination
            totalItems: $scope.players.length,
            currentPage: 1,
            maxSize: 5,
            pages: buildPages()
        }
    };
    var cache = $scope.players;   // save original player model for later use


    /**********
     * Watchers
     **********/

    // watch for filter model changes, start filtering
    $scope.$watch('filters', function(newVal, oldVal){ 
        if (newVal !== oldVal || newVal.id !== oldVal.id || newVal.length !== oldVal.length) {
            var result;

            result = $filter('textFilter')(cache, $scope.filters);                 // filter by phrase
            result = $filter('roleFilter')(result, $scope.filters);                // filter by field position
            result = $filter('teamFilter')(result, $scope.filters.selectedTeamMs); // filter by team

            $scope.players = result;
        }
    }, true);


    /***********
     * Scope API
     ***********/

    // pagination logic
    $scope.changePage  = function(newVal, oldVal) { 
        var maxSize    = $scope.filters.pagination.maxSize;
        var offset     = maxSize * oldVal;
        var result     = [];

        if (newVal < oldVal)  offset = (maxSize * newVal) - maxSize;

        for (var i = 0; i < cache.length; i++) {
            if (i >= offset) result.push(cache[i]);
        }  
        $scope.players = result;
    };


    /****************
     * Helper methods
     ****************/
    function buildPages() {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Is it ok to encapsulate all the logic into that one controller, including helper methods, and so on, or should I refactor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for a better user experience, I would avoid pagination in favour of infinite scroll. [Here is a simple Angular infinite scroll implementation](http://jsbin.com/zusal/2/edit)

I presume you are aware of minification-proof technique `.controller('name', ['$scope', function($scope){}]`, so won't go into that.

Next, I see many fields like `$scope.players`, `$scope.teams`, ..., mixed with `$scope.filters`, which can lead to namespace conflicts as the app grows. Hence I would gather all data-related fields into one object like `$scope.data`. Then you can simply pass the whole object from your service instead of assigning one-by-one.

The hard-coded declation `$scope.predicate = 'team.name';` is mixed with others provided by the service. Perhaps it belongs to a Config service together with other hard-coded properties.

Also I presume you are aware of the difference between using `$scope.field` vs `$scope.field.subfield` in terms of their interactions with parent and child scopes.

EDIT. 
Unless you know what you are doing, a recommended practice is to use `$scope.field.subfield`. That way, in a child controller, you have both read and write access to it. If instead you use `$scope.field`, then changing it from a child controller will add a variable on the local scope but won't change the parent scope as you likely intend, [see here](http://jsbin.com/sibud/2/edit).

EDIT.
See also [Misko's video on best practices](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m), including putting the dot inside your `$scope` property.

`minMax($scope.players);` suggests that you are using service `minMax` just for one function. I would gather those functions into one bigger service like `Utils`. You already have lots of dependencies for your controller, so lowering that number can be a good thing. Similar for `$scope.teams = TeamsModel;`.

I am not sure why you define filters inside a controller, rather than with `.filter` as common.

Usually filters declared via `.filter` update themselves, so no need for watchers.

Comment: 1. How can $scope.xy lead to namespace conflicts, when the scope is bound to the current controller? 2. Why encapsulate all data into one service? I'll need each service individually in other controllers, and passing around both as one seems like a waste. 3. How can those filters be defined, when the code correctly executes filters that are passed with the $filter provider and are defined elswhere? 4. How can a filter update itself, when I don't watch for either model changes in the controller, or in the template?

Comment: As a follow up, the pagination is in place out of performance constrains of older devices, like the original iPad, whose responsiveness gets worse as you add DOM nodes. The desktop version will use the infinite scroll as you suggest. And can you elaborate on the $scope.field vs $scope.field.subfield issue?

Comment: 1. Namespace conflict will occur in the same controller as it grows. 2. You don't need each service, you need the API service provides. 3. Filters are meant to be used inside HTML. Otherwise the shouldn't be called filters to avoid confusion. 4. If I see it right, you are trying to implement filter's functionality by hand in your controller, whereas the Angular way is to define it in you `.filter()` block and use inside HTML.

Comment: If performance is an issue, you can only keep the visible part and slightly above and below inside the DOM. I find infinite scrolling even more convenient on a device, where scroll is so much easier than navigating the tiny page buttons.

Comment: Here is also great explanation why not to use primitives on `$scope`: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/

Comment: One more question that ties in with refactoring code out of the controller - I now have a

Comment: Yes, everything except directly glueing your models to views is generally advised to take out of controller. All configs, filters, helpers... Also you can use `angular.equals` to compare objects in your watcher (but then again, using Angular filters would remove the need for the watcher here in first place).

Comment: So the controller just serves the scope and calls service APIs? I got two separate data models defined as services, but need to manipulate both at one point. Is it advised to directly manipulate one service from the other, or delegate the communication into the controller? E.g. one model are the players, the other one is the playing field, and adding a player to the field should update the playing field layout, as well as flagging the player as added.

Comment: Anyway, sorry for bugging you more with this, I'll take your advice to heart and start refactoring stuff out of the controller.

Comment: Exactly, here is a great article on precisely that: http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/04/08/refactoring-angularjs-get-hands-filthy/. Your data services provide the API to manipulate the data, used from controller. Controller can send raw data to the model service like `field.addPlayer(player)`, which can in turn update the player.